# Problem starting BSC Full Node - GraphQLPort is not defined in node.config

Tags: error, bsc, binance

Trying to start running a full node as per the steps here: https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html

Upon running the last step, "Start your full node"

```
## start a full node
geth --config ./config.toml --datadir ./node
```

I get this error, and the node fails to start.

```
INFO [05-10|01:29:48.318] Starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet... 
INFO [05-10|01:29:48.318] Bumping default cache on mainnet         provided=1024 updated=4096
Fatal: ./config.toml, line 43: field 'GraphQLPort' is not defined in node.Config, see https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/node#Config for available fields
```

How can I fix this, and get the node running? Any help is much appreciated!